# GIT: fatal: ambiguous argument 'FETCH_HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: github, git

I'm working on branch of my git repository and I'm trying to reset all my changes using:

```
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'FETCH_HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Is the first I get this kind error reseting my changes on my repositories. Any of knows why or way around this error to reset my repository?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why are you running that command in the first place? `FETCH_HEAD` contains data left behind by `git fetch`, which is specifically meant only for the `git pull` code to use, and not for anything else. It happens to work for other commands *sometimes* but it's not designed for them.

Comment: I was using FETCH_HEAD to delete my local changes and update with my remote repository

Comment: It's much more typical to do, e.g., `git reset --hard origin/master` (to wipe out all your own work in your own `master` and resynchronize with `origin/master`, which is your Git's memory of origin's master branch). You would do that after running `git fetch origin`, or just `git fetch` which usually defaults to origin. The question is, where did you see instructions telling you to use `FETCH_HEAD`? They are probably wrong.

Comment: @torek, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overwrite any local changes and synchronize your repo to "origin", run these commands:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin
```

This is also useful when you rewrite git history with a rebase and `git push -f` to origin.

I use this when I'm working on changes on my dev system and building on a remote server.  I don't necessarily want all of the little back and forth changes in my git history so I rebase and squash, but then a normal pull will not work on the remote server because the histories no longer align.